# Why we are using the method -(id)init and what are the uses?

Tags: ios, objective-c

While referring a sample code i found this snippet can any explain why it is used.

```
- (id)init
{
  self = [super init];
  if (self) {
  [[self view]setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];    
 }
return self;
}
```

and what is the difference between the following snippet.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
 [super viewDidLoad]; 
 self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
}
```

Comment: init runs at object creation time, viewDidLoad runs when the view is added to the layout, probably more correct to set the background colour in the viewDidLoad

Comment: Fonix is there any advantages using -(id)init

Comment: not really, but unlikely that the subviews etc are ready to have their attributes set inside `init` so safer to stick with `viewDidLoad`

Comment: Fonix tank u ..

Comment: You need to spend some time with basic tutorials on the Objective-C programming language. Understanding what the `init` method is is a very basic bit of knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

init and viewDidLoad both are completely different.

viewDidLoad called, when the view is loaded into memory, this method called once during the life of the **view controller** object. It's a great place to do any view initialization.

init method is an initializer method. Cocoa has various types of intializer. To learn more, please check the link,
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/Initialization/Initialization.html